# How to avoid min value 0 in input type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to avoid the min value 0 for my input type.
I am using following jquery but it allows to enter 0.

```
$('input.numeric').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    return (e.which != 8 && e.which > 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) ? false : true;
})
```

I tried to make it with html-5 setting attribute type="number" but unfortunately mozila does not support it.

I just want my input type to accept the numeric other grater than 0, not decimal at all or any thing else.

Comment: Just use a polyfil for `number` input type : https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By refactoring your `return` statement, with a direct and more readable way, you can get something like this:

```js
    $('input.numeric').bind('keypress', function (e) {
         return (e.which > 48 && e.which <= 57)            // If it's a number between 1 and 9
                 || (e.which == 48 && $(this).val() != "") // Or 0 and the field isn't empty
                 || e.which == 8;                          // Or backspace
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type a number: <input class="numeric" type="text" />
```

Be aware this validation doesn't allow the user to use directional arrow in your field though... And a server-side verification is always mandatory, since the user can disable JS. Even though Firefox does not support it, you should use `type="number"`.

Answer (score 1):

**You could also do this;**
`<input type='number' min='1'>`

**EDIT**

```
$("input.numeric").focusout(function() {
    if($("input.numeric").val() < 1){
        $("input.numeric").val(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: thats true but mozilla do not support the attribute number.